# Hibernate 2 delete all

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently I'm working with one of the oldest product of our company. It uses hibernate 2. I need to delete all the rows of an entity. But I couldn't find a way to execute a query like "delete from com.Entity". And couldn't find a method to delete all. Only session.delete(obj) is available. Please help me to delete all the rows of an entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method, so you'll need to write your own query like this one:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from Entity").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: is this hibernate 2? Hibernate 2 doesn't have executeUpdate method in Query class

Comment: @isurujay Which exactly dependencies for hibernate are used in your project?

Comment: This is hibernate 2 with net.sf.hibernate package structure. No JPA

Comment: So dependencies?

Comment: This is an ant build project. not a maven. Anyway hibernate 2 works alone